# When is {!s} meaningful in format()?

Tags: python

```
>>> import math
>>> print "{} {!s} {!r}".format(math.pi, math.pi, math.pi)
3.14159265359 3.14159265359 3.141592653589793
```

When is the `!s` inside `{}` meaningful?

Or in other words, when is calling `str()` on a `format()` argument meaningful?

Answer (score 2):

Whenever the type to be printed implements `__format__` in an an unsuitable way for your purpose. In this case, you can use `!s` or `!r` (and I think there is even `!a`) to specify an alternate formatter.

You certainly won't need it for printing floating-point numbers, but probably for custom types.

Comment: +1: For custom types which implement `__str__` should be first.